# not able to load external json file using d3.js

Tags: jquery, json, d3.js

I am trying to load external json file and use it with d3.js but it does not seem to load (i cannot see the us-states.json file in the browser)the file and i cannot find any relevant error. Here is my code :-

I am getting this error :- `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/us-states.json"):`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                      //Width and height
        var w = 500;
        var h = 300;

        //Define map projection
        var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
                           .translate([w/2, h/2])
                           .scale([500]);

        //Define path generator
        var path = d3.geo.path()
                    .projection(projection);

        //Create SVG element
        var svg = d3.select("#testing")
                                .append("svg")
                                .attr("width", w)
                                .attr("height", h);

        //Load in GeoJSON data
        // json = JSON.parse( "us-states.json" );
        // var json = {"my": "json"};
        d3.json("us-states.json", function(error, json) {
                if (error) return console.warn(error);
                //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
                svg.selectAll("path")
                   .data(json.features)
                   .enter()
                   .append("path")
                   .attr("d", path)
                   .style("fill", "steelblue");

        });
});
```

The file us-state.json is in the same folder where my javascript file is.

**Update**

The error in javascript console is this :-

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

in file us-states.json

Attached screenshot to show file is in the project folder :- [image]

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not seem to load"?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff i mean i cannot see the us-states.json file in the browser

Comment: That would suggest that it's not there. Double-check that you've uploaded it to the correct place.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yes it is in the same folder i also get this error ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/us-states.json"):

Comment: That suggests that something is wrong in your webserver configuration.

Comment: i think the issue is how d3 is referencing json file, if i create a route for it this works, however it is not able to load data from a file

Comment: What's the error message you're getting in the Javascript code?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @LarsKotthoff i have attached the screenshot to show file exist

Comment: You've told us nothing about your webserver setup/configuration. The browser say it's not there so something must be wrong there. In any case, your problem isn't caused by/related to D3.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff it is a rails application, is there some other way to load it with rails ?

Comment: There are several questions on this very subject already, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983935/how-to-show-d3-js-graph-in-a-rails-application).

Answer (score 0):

What file is that code in? index.html (or some equivalent?)

You don't have any web files in the folder you are showing with the json file. The json file needs to be in the same folder as the page that called the javascript, not the same folder as d3.js

So, lets say your web file is in your root directory, which you call d3-project, then the correct path would be: app/assets/javascripts/us-states.json

Also, it's an internal file, since you already have it on your server. External would imply that you are hitting a web server other than your own and downloading it.

Comment: code is in home.html, i have tried giving the path too but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

You can also just stick that us-states.json file into your public folder and treat it as though it were local (i.e. leave your code as-is).

See this for an example of a d3 map in a Rails app:
https://github.com/lisafeather/map_in_app